# How can I change the feature path? (SP2010 with VS2012)

Tags: 2010, visual-studio-2012

Features are deployed to the 14 hive in the features subfolder. By default the name of the feature folder is `{projectname}_{FeatureName}`.

How can I change the path the feature is deployed to?

E.g.
My Visual Studio project is called Proj1 and my feature is called Feat1.
By default the feature creates the folder Proj1_Feat1.
However I would like it to be CompanyName.Proj1_Feat1 without using the company name in my projectname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change this name, double-click on the feature in the “Solution Explorer” view to display the feature properties. Under properties, you’ll see the feature’s “Deployment Path” property, which by default is set to:

```
$SharePoint.Project.FileNameWithoutExtension$_$SharePoint.Feature.FileNameWithoutExtension$
```

The first token is the project name and the second token is the feature name. Change the feature so that the name is your custom name by setting the “Deployment Path”

Comment: Great, thanks.
I saw this answer before but couldn't find it. Now I have ;)